# Using Django's new i18n_patterns: How to fall back to the default language specified in the settings module?

Tags: python, django, internationalization, url-routing, urlconf

I'm using the new `i18n_patterns` of Django 1.4:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

It works for every active language:

```
/en/admin/ # Ok
/es/admin/ # Ok
```

But this fails:

```
/admin/ # 404 Not found
```

How to avoid the 404 error and redirect to a language-prefixed version of the requested URL (not only the admin panel)?

Is to write a custom middleware the solution? Why this doesn't come by default in Django?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like you did not [enable django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-url-patterns).

Comment: Oops... My bad! I guess the docs needs to clarify this a little more. However after reading the whole translation section it becomes clear that `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` is pretty much needed for everything on translation. Thanks!

Comment: Answer still applies to Django 1.9.